# How to wirte SQL query that will return name of the person when weight is over certain value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table line and I want to know how to write SQL query that will return the name of the person when weight reaches over 1000.

```
create table line(
id int not null PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar(255) not null,
weight int not null,
turn int unique not null,
check (weight > 0));
```

This is what I have so far this should return all rows before we reach 1000, but I only want to see the name of the person that comes after we reach this.

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM 
  line AS t1 
LEFT JOIN line AS t2 
  ON t2.id = t1.id 
WHERE t1.id  > 1 
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.weight, t1.turn
HAVING COALESCE(SUM(t2.weight),0) < 1000;
```

Comment: "...the person that comes after we reach this..." -- table rows don't have inherent ordering. You'll need to define how the query should consider that a row is **before** or **after** another one.

Comment: Change `SELECT t1.*` to `SELECT t1.name`

Comment: Do you need only one value? Like the name of the person where is weight == 1001?